# Trimming a string in php and assigning it to two fields in database

Tags: php

I have provided a textarea in my webpage where the user will provide data as:

```
  15-05-2013, Allen Birthday;
  19-06-2013, Rosie Birthday;
  5-07-2013, Annie Birthday;
```

and so on.

When they hit the submit button, I want to trim the data, sentence wise and add it to the database. For, each row, the string before (comma) should be assigned to one variable and the string after (comma) till (semicolon) should be assigned to another variable.
That will be stored in the database and again same happens with the next row.

Please help me!

Comment: Check out [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place to describe a problem and receive a solution. You need to put in effort to devise your own solution, then demonstrate what you have tried and how the results of that solution differ from your expectations.

Comment: why not have the users fill in a form with multiple input fields making this a lot easier than splitting a textarea

Comment: @Dagon Maybe the data is copy and paste'ed in from another application? I have quite a few forms where users copy and paste out of excel and I process the data on the fly.

Comment: maybe the moon is made from chesses, you can guess  all you like

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
foreach($row as $value)
{
    $tmp = explode(",",$value);
    $a = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($tmp[0]));
    $b = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($tmp[1]));
    mysql_query("insert into table_name (`col1`,`col2`) values ('{$a}','{$b}')");

}
```

Comment: This solution does not show how to spilt the inputin single lines. Also it's very dangerous to insert `$a` and `$b` directly in the mysql query (SQL Injection), so never ever do this!

Comment: added code for sql injection

Comment: one more thing to note in `mysql_real_escape_string`, `mysql` extension is depricated in current version, Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used

Answer (score 0):

php has a function that will do this for you [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$data  = "15-05-2013, Allen Birthday";
$pieces = explode(",", $data);
print_r($pieces);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explode the initial string you get passed into an array of rows like this:

```
$yourText=explode('\r\n', $yourTextAreaInput);
```

then you can split each row of data into parts like this:

```
$singleLine=explode(',', $yourText[element]);
// where element is the row number starting with 0 (Do it in a loop perhaps)
```

then you might want to trim whitespace around it so it will be neat and tdiy like this:

```
$part2=trim(singleLine[1]);
```

Comment: Also make shure to validate all the Data before you insert it into your database. i.e. are there allways two values per line, does the text contain bad characters, ...

Answer (score 0):

explode and you will get your values in an array format

```
$input = "15-05-2013, Allen Birthday";
$dataArr = explode(",", $input);
$var1 = current($dataArr);
$var2 = trim(end($dataArr));

// $var1 will have 15-05-2013
// $var2 will have Allen Birthday
```